# Cytoscape.js - detecting if any nodes have been selected on boxend

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I'm subscribing to the `boxend` event on my cytoscape instance which is correctly firing, but I want to be able to determine whether any nodes were within the box when the event fired. It appears that Event `target` property is just the cytoscape instance, rather than the elements that were selected.

This is the sort of thing I'm hoping to do.

```
this.cy.on('boxend', event => {

  if (event.nodesSelected()) {
    // fire off some action
  } else {
    console.log('no nodes selected');
  }

});
```

I can think of a workaround using the `boxstart` to set a flag `nodesSelected = false` and then setting `nodesSelected = true` on the `box`/`boxselect` events, but this doesn't seem ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also listen to `box` if you want to know about the entire gesture flow.  From the docs:

box : triggered on elements when inside the box on boxend

http://js.cytoscape.org/#events/user-input-device-events

Generally for UI, it suffices to use debouncing with events like `box`.

```
let boxedNodes = cy.collection();

let handleElements = debounce(function(){
  // ...

  boxedNodes = cy.collection();
});

cy.on('box', function( e ){
  let node = e.target;

  boxedNodes = boxedNodes.union( node );

  handleElements();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply maxkfranz. I believe this solution is somewhat similar to my workaround suggestion but uses a debounce and collection instead of a flag. I was hoping for an event that would only fire once per selection, but I'll mark this as accepted for now.